# How to extract int day, month and year from string ID in C++

Tags: c++, class

I started doing this program at the university, but I have some functions left for doing at home: `getBirthday` and `age`. How can I get day, month, year as ints from the string ID?

I've tried to work only with string but it is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum Sex {male,female,unknown};  //const
class Person   //class
{
private:
    string name;
    string ID;   //this is the problem
    Sex pol;
....
void getBirthday(int &day,int&month,int&year)  //even if i use string for day...it is not working
{}
...
int main()
{Person p1("ALEX","9510167954")...;}   //95-year,10-month,16-day*this is what my teacher wrote
```

I expect the output: 16/10/95

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? As you posted it, your code doesn't even compile...

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the `getBirthday( )` parameters as below:

```
day = stoi(ID.substr(0,2));
month = stoi(ID.substr(2, 2));
year = stoi(ID.substr(4, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the standard [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) stream manipulator. You can use [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the `ID` string as a stream.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

void getBirthday(int &day, int &month, int &year)
{
    std::istringstream iss(ID);
    std::tm t = {};
    iss >> std::get_time(&t, "%y%m%d");
    if (iss.fail()) {
        // do something, like throw an exception ...
    }
    day = t.tm_mday;
    month = 1 + t.tm_mon;
    year = 1900 + t.tm_year;
}
```